# Passing 'records' parameter to Pandas to_dict method

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a dataframe that I'd like to convert to a dictionary. I want each column in the dataframe to be mapped to the values in it.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

data = np.random.randn(5,5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
dict1 = df.to_dict(outtype = 'records')
```

Here is the error I get:

> Value Error: outtype records not understood

However, when I check the [docs](http://bit.ly/1b34mNv) for this method, records is listed as a valid parameter. Moreover, I am able to convert my dataframe to all the other dictionary formats mentioned in docs (list, series, and dict). I'm not sure what could be going wrong.

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using; can check via `import pandas` `pandas.__version__`

Comment: IIRC, this was added in 0.13 (which is out now).

Comment: Ah, I am using version .12. I'll update to .13. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff: Somewhere you could mention that all questions provide Pandas; NumPy, etc versions..Makes life easier for you

Comment: @NipunBatra I agree...but people dont' read instructions IMHO :)

Comment: I edited this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info (may not be visible for a while)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dict1 = df.to_dict('records')
```