# How can I use Requests with a Pandas dataframe to create multiple Get http request?

Tags: python, pandas, get, python-requests

I am a hobby programmer and would like to solve a real-world problem I am having.  I am a user of a software system that exposes an api that allows one to update/add records using Get.  I have the imported the data I would like to modify the system with into Pandas and don't know the best way to iterate over the rows and dynamically create a URL.

I would like to create a URL for each row that is similar to:

http://fakesite.org/servlet/Erp?_form=AD1&_EVT=ADD&_RTN=DATA&FC=Add&_f1=A&_f3=HELLO&f16=EA&_OUT=XML&_EOT=TRUE

below I have included the beginning of my code setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as r

site = 'http://fakesite.org/servlet/Erp?'

payload = dict()
payload['_FORM'] = 'AD1'
payload['_EVT'] = 'ADD'
payload['_RTN'] = 'DATA'
payload['FC'] = 'Add'
payload['_OUT'] = 'XML'
payload['_EOT'] = 'TRUE'

data = {'F1': ['A','A','A'], 'F3': ['HELLO', 'GOODBYE', 'HELLO_AGAIN'], 'F16': ['EA','BX','CA']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The "payload" dictionary I created is all the parameters that don't change for the request, these are essentially hard coded and not a part of the pandas data frame.  I will ultimately combine this dictionary with the values in each row of the data frame before passing it to request.get

I think I need to use either use either apply or itterrows but I can't seem to figure it out.

How should I write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use pandas, you can get a list of payloads to iterate through with

```
F1  = ['A','A','A']
F3  = ['HELLO', 'GOODBYE', 'HELLO_AGAIN']
F16 = ['EA','BX','CA']

payloads = [dict(payload,**{'F1': F1, 'F3': F3, 'F16': F16}) for F1,F3,F16 in zip(F1,F3,F16)]
```

EDIT:
If you must use pandas then, you could use `to_dict('records')` as discussed in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815129/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-dictionaries-dics). Then, the documents explain how to [formulate the actual requests.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

```
payloads = [dict(payload, **params) for params in df.to_dict('records')]
gets = [requests.get(site, params=payload) for payload in payloads]
# to check that the urls were as you thought
for r in gets:
    print r.url
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  To continue this exercise, how would you pass the "payloads" to the Requests library so that it produces a request per dictionary?  Also, could you do this with the Pandas function "to-dict('records')"?  I am using Pandas to manipulate the data, then I am getting it into the dataframe that will be used for the request variable parameters.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190323/passing-records-parameter-to-pandas-to-dict-method